# Что делать с вопросами по ImportError?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Я заметил, что в последнее время на сайте появилось много вопросов по одной и той же ошибке Python:

> ImportError: No module named...

Вопросы эти по отдельности слабо помогают человеку, зашедшему на них из поисковика, потому как ясного и четкого ответа на них, как правило, нет.

Наверное, имеет смысл перечислить в одном вопросе все возможные причины подобной ошибки и все дальнейшие подобные вопросы закрывать как дубликаты.

На всякий случай даю ссылку на [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ImportError) подобных вопросов (можете убедиться в его размерах)

Comment: Похоже, такой вопрос уже есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/507426.

Comment: Есть, но на основном сайте. Так что это не дубликат. (на мету я вопрос перенес не по своей воле) Чтож, хорошо, теперь понятно на что закрывать такие вопросы.

Comment: Я имел ввиду именно тот вопрос, который вы предлагали создать.

Comment: Кстати, это совсем не то! Я невнимательно посмотрел. Это по другому вопросу, если ты сам модуль написал и он не импортируется.

Comment: @wchistow тамошний ответ навязывает conda, мне это не нравится

Comment: Для Меты, кмк, вопрос в текущем виде тоже не подходит. Если хочется узнать можно ли создавать вопросы с развёрнутым описанием решения, покрывающие функционал сразу нескольких похожих вопросов и закрывать их дубликатом - то это как раз приветствуется.